# How to understand "continue current" parameter of drone motor?

Tags: motor, current-sensor

I installed to drone four motors which has continue current parameter of 30A. So, I assume that my drone should take 120A from battery, but maximum value that showed in my goggles is 7A.

So, how does it work? How to understand this value? Is it OK that I'm using batteries with XT60? Can the maximum current be limited for safety reasons (protect battery from huge current)?